# How to differentiate Whether a Drive or NetWork Drive, on RightClick

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions

When I Rightclick on a Shell Drive I want to differentiate whether the Drive is a Normal Drive or a Network Drive.

I hope we can do this using `Initialize(LPCITEMIDLIST, LPDATAOBJECT, HKEY)` method but unsure which parameter to use.

Comment: What interface is that Initialize called on?

Comment: @Goz, IShellExtInit is the Interface which Contains Initialize method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Initialize` is now documented to take a `PCIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` (not `LPCITEMIDLIST`), so you know it's rooted in My Desktop. My Computer is the second ItemID on that list, and the drive is the third ItemID. As Luke indicated, once you have the drive, `GetDriveType` will tell you whether the drive is remote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939.aspx).